# Where string data goes in memory

Tags: go, memory

I read that Strings are immutable and internally string has two data, first one is pointer and second one is length of pointed data.

```
s := "Hello World"
```

This means s has two data pointer of bytes of strings and length is 11 and if we change this data

```
s = "This is golang"
```

then `s` will contain different pointer and length but I am not getting if these bytes of string that s was pointing stored in a stack or in heap?

Also, we can get the string from a file and assign it to `s` variable means at compile time compiler won't know the number of bytes to store, so would be heap in?

Comment: This question cannot be answered. From a language perspective there is neither heap nor stack. Implementations may do whatever they like, especially for string constant they will neither be stack nor heap allocated. Additionally: The answer for lets say a particular compiler like tinygo, gcc or the wasm port are non-actionable: You cannot _do_ anything useful with that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String literals are stored in the data segment. They cannot change.

Strings created dynamically at runtime are stored either on stack or in heap, depending on how the strings are allocated/used. If a string is used within a function and does not live beyond that function, it is likely that it will be on stack. Otherwise it will be in heap.

Comment: String literals might be in rodata or text, rather than regular data. A Go compiler targeting a microcontroller with separate ROM and RAM should probably put them in the text segment, for instance. Other than inspecting the generated code, it's not really possible to tell where the compiler put them, so (since microcontrollers aren't the usual target) I'm not sure why we should care in most cases...

Answer (score 0):

`String` is const after it's been created. If you reassign a String var, the compiler just creates another const String, abandon the previous one, the previous one will wait for GC.